# Is it possible to use Docusign Gen in a custom apex button?

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign Gen works great for generating a document, but it won't let me set new defaults for the email messsages or signing order. With APEX custom coding these are possible to set, but i'm not sure if it's possible to have the docusign gen part run first, then send out the documents with the right email messaging and signing order.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible, but we do hope to have this capability in the future.
While I cannot promise any dates, I'll be sure to update this post when I have more information.